# PHP search multiple fields issue

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I'm working through this tutorial online: http://goo.gl/qnk6U

The database table: ajax_search

```
Firstname | Lastname | Age | Hometown | Job
-------------------------------------------
Joe       | Smith    | 35  | Boulder  | CIA   
Steve     | Apple    | 36  | Denver   | FBI
```

(Types are all varchar except age is an int.)

My question.  Is the sql select statement below written correctly to query "Joe 35"?  For some reason, I can only query "Joe" and it works, but not combining search terms.

```
$sql = "select * from ajax_search where FirstName like '%$rec%' or LastName like '%$rec%' or Age like '%$rec%' or Hometown like '%$rec%'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your query is "Joe 35", then no. Your query matches any row where any of the four fields contains "Joe 35" (in a single field). To query for a user with name Joe and age 35, you'd need to split the search query and do something like:

```
WHERE Firstname LIKE "$firstname" AND Age LIKE "$age"
```

Comment: That makes sense, thanks.  Is it possible however to do a search like this not knowing what combination of terms the user will type?

Comment: You can, although it can get quite complex and that's where my knowledge fades! Try reading http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to split that sting from search query:

```
$columns = array("Firstname", "Lastname", "Age", "Hometown", "Job");
$string = ""; // acquire query string
$split = explode(" ", $string);
$search_words = array();
foreach ($split as $word) {
   $search_words[] = $word;
}
```

Create query to search all over the fields:

```
$first = true;
$sql = "select * from ajax_search where";
foreach ($search_words as $word) {
   foreach ($columns as $col) {
      $sql .= (($first) ? " " : " OR") . "`$col` LIKE \"%" . $word . "%\"";
      $first = false;
   }
}
```

Then run this query.

Another and also a better solution would be more complicated word(tag) based indexing, because this can generate **morbid queries** when used with more words.

Comment: Hey thanks!  Your example above, can I then search "Joe Boulder" etc..?

Comment: Yes in th is example you can search combination of anz field. Eg. Joe Smith, Smith 35, 35 CIA, Joe Smith CIA, simply one or more fields in any combinations.

Comment: get me a var_dump of $string - variable passed as query string to our php script, please.